# My search bar doesn't display the searched content in my table view

Tags: swift

I feel stuck at the moment with this search bar. It successfully connect to my SQL database and my search.php file successfully search and prints the searched content. It won't show results in my table view and when I type a song in the search bar and press done it does nothing. I will show my whole SearchViewController code and ill add any additional files if necessary. Any help would be appreciated!

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/search.php")
var filteredData: [Search] = []
var shouldShowSearchResults = false
var search: [Search] = []
var filePath = "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/search.php"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, snapshot, error) in
         

           let retrievedList = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                 print(retrievedList!)
                 self.parseSongs(data: retrievedList!)
                }
task.resume()
}

func parseSongs (data: String) {
  
    if (data.contains("*")) {
        let dataArray = (data as String).split(separator: "*").map(String.init)
        for item in dataArray {
            let itemData = item.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
            let searchSong = Search(songname: itemData[0])
    search.append(searchSong!)
        
            for s in search {
            print(s.searchSongName())
        }
            self.filteredData = self.search
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
      }
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell
    let song = filteredData[indexPath.row].searchSongName()
    cell.congigureCell(text: song)
    return cell
    
}
        
        

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let searchSong = filteredData[indexPath.row].searchSongName()
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(searchSong)"
    print(fileURLString)

}
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if (searchBar.text ?? "").isEmpty {
           
        view.endEditing(true)
        
           
        filteredData = search
       
       } else {
            shouldShowSearchResults = true
        filteredData = search.filter({ (songName) -> Bool in
            songName.searchSongName().range(of: searchText) != nil
        })
       }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
   }
}
```

Search.swift:

```
class Search {

var search: Search!

var songname = String()

init?(songname:String) {
    self.songname = songname
}

func searchSongName() -> String {
    return songname
}
}
```

Comment: check if delegate methods are getting called ?

Comment: What does the searchSongName do? Can you post the code for that function. Like @jawadAli said, try adding print statements inside your searchBar function to see whether the if or else statements get called (if any at all).

Comment: @rs7 I added my search.swift file that has that function and I will try what you said thank you

Comment: @rs7 Where should I put the print statements in the searchBar? Also searchSongName get the song name from my sql database

Comment: You can add 3 print statements inside the textDidChange function: 1 before the ifelse block, one in the if block, and one in the else block. That's a starting point and that'll tell you if the function gets executed at all, and if it does, do the other print statements get printed as expected.

Comment: When you say it's not printing anything in the tableView, you mean the tableView methods are not getting called?  In this case, I would try embedding the tableView.reloadData() statement at the end of your searchBar textDidChange function inside a DispatchQueue.main.async { } block to explicitly run it on the main thread.

Comment: I just updated the search bar function, but the search bar is not displaying the text that I search for. Also, whenever I press Done on the keyboard nothing happens.